# Youtube streaming slowly on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, youtube

I am facing issues streaming Youtube videos on iPad (using the native Youtube app)

My connection speed is 3.1 Mbps, which I guess is decent for video streaming. Also I agree that I would not get the full 3.1 Mbps and would only get about 1/3rd. So I get around 1 Mbps based on speedtest.

Now what should I do to fix the Youtube streaming and is it a known issue with speed limits for the Youtube app ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using 3G or Wi-Fi?

Comment: I am using a 3.1 Mbps Wifi connection..

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes a problem when there are a large number of apps open at once, or the iPad is otherwise running low on memory.

I have an iPad 1, and unless I set the quality fairly low, there is no guarantee I will get a decent viewing experience.

To try and fix this, first close all apps but youtube, then, if that doesn't work, reboot your device.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently have this problem with YouTube (old iOS native app and googles official version). And  I have a 20Mb connection. I have just replaced the official app with a free alternative called Jasmine from the AppStore and its so much quicker. Prior to this I was using the mobile website, which was also quite a bit quicker.